# Can't see elements inside div in my HTML code?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am working on an application that has a form on one of its pages. The form is enclosed in a bunch of nested div tags. It looks something like this:

```
<main id="main-body">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="formContainer>
            <div data-reactid=".0">
                <div data-reactid=".0">
                    <div data-reactid=".0.0.1.$form">
                        <form id="myForm" data-reactid=".0.0.1.$form.1">
                            ...
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

The trouble is that I can see the form on my webpage, and also through the 'View Source' function in my browser, but when I do an 'Inspect Element' to see the actual HTML being generated, I just see

```
<main id="main-body">
    <div id="content-wrapper">
        <div id="formContainer">
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

I can't see any of the HTML elements inside the div 'formContainer' when I do an 'Inspect Element', even though they are right there on the page. Any ideas as to why might this be? I need to get the form Id in Neoload, but Neoload just won't read it, since it's absent from the page's source.

Edit: Several of the div tags are using `data-reactid=".0.0"`. The form element itself has `data-reactid=".0.0.1.$form.1"`. Basically anything with `react` disappears. I know nothing of React. Could this be causing this issue? I have updated my code to match the original code more closely.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Could you elaborate?

Comment: Probably malformed HTML somewhere. A good IDE should highlight any issues for you, but you could also try passing it through a [validator](https://validator.w3.org).

Comment: Aren't you removing the `<form>` element somewhere else by mistake ?

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the `id="form-container"`! A `"` is missing

Comment: That's just an error I made while copying the code, it's not there in the actual application.

Comment: You are not closing something for sure! If you use any js framework it may cause the problem as well! It would be great if you could give as the whole original code (use a snippet)

Comment: You can use "view page source" instead of "inspect element" for seeing where is the problem.